# Enable fullscreen Vimeo video button on fancyBox v3

Tags: jquery, fancybox, vimeo, vimeo-player, fancybox-3

Using fancyBox v3 to load Vimeo videos, and all is working great except there is no fullscreen button enabled. The documentation says you can add parameters to the URL passed through to fancybox, but I cannot seem to find a fullscreen URL parameter (it usually goes into the iframe tag). The iframe tag generated does have the webkitallowfullscreen, mozallowfullscreen, etc, but there is no button to make the video itself fullscreen (particularly an issue on mobile).

Using the following code:

`<a data-fancybox href="{VIMEOLINK}">VIDEO TITLE</a>`

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have an example page where your code is deployed and the Vimeo Player is lacking the fullscreen button?

Comment: Yes, lovethewoods.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fullscreen button is hidden by Vimeo when player enters "Mini mode" (https://help.vimeo.com/hc/en-us/articles/224972808-Customizing-the-embedded-player). Try to shrink your browser and you will see that the player will enter "Tiny mode" first and then only play button will be visible.

You can remove free space around the video (reserved for navigation arrows) to make player wider and then "Mini mode" would kick in just for tiny screens.

```
.fancybox-slide--video { 
    padding: 0; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This does help keep the video bigger, but I am still not seeing the fullscreen button on even the widest of screens (even when the video is large, over 2000px wide)

Comment: Really? And what about official demos on the homepage or here - https://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/gopGNq?editors=1010 ? Works fine for me. What device and browser are you using?

Comment: Oh, I just now saw your other comment where you mentioned your page. Seems that your issue is not related to fancybox, see this demo - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qYaYwM?editors=1000 and check out this article - https://help.vimeo.com/hc/en-us/articles/115015759768-Fullscreen-button-missing-from-the-player

Comment: YES YES YES THAT IS IT! Wow-- didn't even consider it to be a Vimeo level thing, but sure enough, the Vimeo embed settings weren't calling for a fullscreen button. Added it and now working beautifully. Thank you so much!